# how to enable two-finger scrolling on Asus Zenbook / Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: touchpad, asus, multi-touch, scrolling

Just installed Ubuntu 15.10 alongside windows 10. Touchpad generally works (clicking, dragging, moving cursor) but two-finger scroll does not work.

Using Asus Zenbook UX305UA. I've seen some other threads with different Zenbook models and different Ubuntu versions, and the packages people have suggested don't work.

I think I have an Elantech touchpad, because I see:

```
$ grep -i pad /proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="Elan Touchpad"
```

In addition, it looks like the system is not recognizing that it is a touchpad. In System Preferences->Mouse and Trackpad, I see "Mouse" but not "Trackpad".

It was suggested that my question is a duplicate, but the proposed duplicate is for a different machine. The fact that the answer to the other question does not work for me confirms that the difference between the models is meaningful, and that the answer to this question will be different.

As requested in comments, output of `xinput` is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Did you try **System Settings -->Mouse & Touched -->☑Two Finger Scroll**?

Comment: I don't see that option there.

Comment: You dont have [**this** option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VBr7X.png)???

Comment: Yes, that it true. It does not show up as touchpad, it shows up as mouse options.

Comment: seems like some driver issue

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto That won't work. This is a completely different touchpad.

Comment: This problem have been solved in kernel 4.4, i had the similar problem. After upgrading the kernel, problem resolved and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 and the touchpad should work OK with kernel 4.4.

There is no supported way to install kernel 4.4 to Ubuntu 15.10.

It can be installed only to 14.04, or 16.04.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/564019)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto This IS an answer, not a comment. ))

Comment: «How to enable two-finger scrolling on Ubuntu 15.10» → «Use Ubuntu 16.04»? Not really an answer. If you want to say to the OP that it works with kernel 4.4 in 16.04, write a comment.

Comment: I installed 16.04 instead, but now the touchpad doesn't work. In system settings it recognizes that it is a touchpad, not a mouse, but I can't move the pointer, click, or scroll with it.

Comment: This means that the 4.4 kernel does detect the touchpad, but not fully support it. Maybe some boot options are needed to get it work.  What does `xinput` show. Add it to your question.

Comment: I've found now that with 16.04, the touchpad works spottily. To be precise, the touchpad is never recognized immediately after starting the computer. Sometimes, closing and re-opening is enough to make it recognized. When that doesn't work, plugging in a USB mouse and unplugging it can make it work. I shared the output of `xinput` as requested

Answer (score 0):

This problem have been solved in kernel 4.4,
 You can install kernel 4.4 to Ubuntu 14.04 without upgrading to 16.04 by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Regarding "how stable is 4.4.6", it can't be answered as it will be based on opinions. For me everything is working fine, many of problems which i had in 3.6 are solved in 4.4